# UIScrollVIew only showing first static subview, delegate of UIPageControl

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I am a newbie of IOS development, my problem is I am using UIScrollView and UIPageControl to show guide info to users. I created a xib file related to **GuideViewController** via setting up **File's Owner**. I setup the content size and statically add subviews in xib files. But I encountered some strange thing, scrollview only shows the first subview on screen, all following display is just white background (when I scrolling).
Following is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    NSInteger numberOfPages = 2;
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = numberOfPages;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;

    self.pageScroll.delegate = self;
    self.pageScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfPages,
                                        self.view.frame.size.height);
    self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth/2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
}
```

I googled a lot to find the answer but still stuck here. 
I am also confused by this sentence **"When a user taps a page control to move to the next or previous page, the control sends the UIControlEventValueChanged event for handling by the delegate"** in xcode help. It seems UIPageControl has no delegate attribute,so how I can capture the **UIControlEventValueChanged** event.

Actually I am developing my main UI on storyboard, but I kind of want separate UI design to make more space for storyboard, so i use xib file for some other part UI, I do not know whether this will cause some problems. Thanks

Comment: I solved first issue already, I thought UIScrollView will arrange subviews for me, but I turned out I need to set subview's origin myself.

Comment: Just awnser your question by yourself. Thank you.

Comment: @MasterRazer But how about the delegate issue. There is no delegate attribute for UIPageControl, how I capture UIControlEventValueChanged event. Thanks. I am still googling that. :)

Comment: wait a sec. I got your result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was this:

Add a IBAction in your header:

```
 - (IBAction)changePage;
```

Dont forget to set the Outlet and the property for the pageControl:

```
IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPageControl* pageControl;
```

Add a BOOLEAN that the pagecontrol updates:

```
BOOL pageControlBeingUsed;
```

Here is my full header:

```
@interface ViewC : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
    IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;

    BOOL pageControlBeingUsed;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView* scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPageControl* pageControl;

- (IBAction)changePage;

@end
```

(Don't forget to synthesize the propertys)
The second step you did already with the viewdidLoad method but you didn't connected the Boolean to the method!  Try this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    if (!pageControlBeingUsed) {
        // Switch the indicator when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
        CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
        int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
        self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
    }
}
```

Add at the end this code for the IBAction and that when the pageControl was pressed at a button the site changes.

```
- (IBAction)changePage {
    // update the scroll view to the appropriate page
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * self.pageControl.currentPage;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];

    pageControlBeingUsed = YES;

}
```

**IMPORTANT**:
Connect the IBAction with "value changed" option in the xib. and set the delegate of the Controller to itself:

[image]

And then it should be like this:
[image]

That is all! Hope you fixed your issue. I would be glad if you give my awnser the "tick" if it helped you!

Greetings,

Noah

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will check this and give you feedback.

Comment: it works!! Also I learn a new way to capture action. Thanks. But I still have a question, why we need add ##if## statement to ##scrollViewDidScroll##. It seems unnecessary.

Comment: it is just for memory handling. The scrollviews can cause memory leaks if there are many items inside. Just leave it as it is! :)